# Why isn't option C correct answer for the given question?

Tags: linear-systems

W[image]

Please answer this question I am getting option c as my answer by putting input frequency of 3 radians in frequency response of system.

Comment: why are you putting in 3? Where does that come from? And the correct solution seems to be given there, too, so where's your question?

Comment: For an lti system with sinusoidal input output is also sinusoidal with magnitude response of system multiplied with the magnitude of sinusoid and phase response of system added with phase of sinusoid. I am applying that concept here. Do you know about it?

Comment: The solution is obtained there. I am not okay with that 1 as phase in O/p it should be 3 instead. Look in the result there is exp-jw multiplied. If you go by time shifting property of fourier transform. It should result in 1/2sin(3(t-1) in time domain not 1/2sin(3t -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, option C is correct. The system is an ideal lowpass filter with a delay of $\tau=1$ eliminating all components with frequencies higher than $\omega_c=4$. Consequently, only the component with index $k=1$ remains, and the only thing that happens to it is that it is delayed by $\tau=1$, i.e., $x(t)=\frac12\sin(3t)$ becomes $x(t-\tau)=\frac12\sin(3(t-\tau))$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt.

Comment: It seems I was too hasty, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi Matt: It's probably a bad question but why do all the components with frequencies higher than $\omega_c = 4$ get eliminated. thanks.

Comment: As he already stated it's a low pass filter. Impluse response is a delayed sampling function. Fourier transform of sampling function is gate pulse. The gate pulse has bandwidth of 4 radiand which is actually a low pass filter with cutt off frequency 4 radians. And unity magnitude. That is why frequencies upto 4 radians is only allowed to pass.